# Having issues with Active Reports passing parameters

Tags: parameters, activereports

Using Active Reports Standalone Designer. Creating a Section Report with unbound data. Trying to pass a parameter to the SQL. The Documentation i've found leads me to believe that this:

" where loan_num = '<%param:cOption1%>'"

should work. cOption1 is defined in Report explorer as a parameter. Any insight as to why this does not work? A link to an example would be very much appreciated.

Thanks,

Emil Garcia

Answer (score 0):

If you're using "unbound data" the SQL won't be interpreted since the SQL is only used when using bound data. You can pass parameters into a report and then use them from the code to retrieve your unbound data.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is correct.  Make sure that loan_num takes in a value with single quotes.  At run time when the query is evaluated it will translate the above into following:
if the value of cOption1 is test:
select * from table where loan_num = 'test'

Make sure a query with this syntax will run in your underlying database.

Are there any errors that you get?

http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/topic132.html